# What is the purpose of Laravel passports .env variable PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am following Laravel's passport documentation and in this section specifically
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/passport#personal-access-tokens

```
PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_ID="client-id-value"
PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET="unhashed-client-secret-value"
```

I tried not putting these .env variable and was able to generate a token like this `$token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;`
without any issue

So what is the purpose for them? I need to understand in order to make better judgment regarding security.